# React Cursor jumping when formatting textfield

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, cursor-position

I know there are a lot of topics on this, and I've done my best reading and implementing their solutions, but I just cant get it to work properly

Im trying to format the phone number so that it displays in a certain format.

I created a demo of how it works in my app.
https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-leaf-94s3w?file=/src/App.js

Edit: sorry to describe the issue a bit more.

everything works fine when you are just typing out a # front to back

but when I try to modify the middle numbers the cursor will jump to the end after each input.

Thanks

Comment: I think you can describe a little how the "jumping cursor" actually happens?

Answer (score 4):

Hi so the problem is that you pass a new value and that will be just like inputing the whole value. And this will cause the cursor to move to the end.

You can overcome it by requesting a window animation frame and move the cursor back to where it was:

```
const caret = target.selectionStart;
    const element = target;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      element.selectionStart = caret;
      element.selectionEnd = caret;
    });
```

Here is a copy of your [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-morse-ot54n?file=/src/Demo.js).

Comment: Thank you! Seems it be working.  I spent 1/2 of yesterday trying to figure this out -_-

Comment: Actually there is a minor bug, if you start with no input whenever a ")" or "-" is added, the cursor ends up in the wrong position, not at the end like before, just 1 behind, seems like it doesnt account for the extra char that was added?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the ref into the wrong element. In `@material-ui/core/TextField` you must pass the ref to the `inputProps` instead of direct ref.

Just change the:

`ref={input}`

to:

`inputProps={{ ref: input }}`

There are other issues in your code such as not parsing the value to the normal string state but the issue for jumping was for `ref`

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work to, but I noticed the cursor still ends up in the wrong place when a ")" or "-" gets added.  whats the best way to fix this?  my first thought is using If statements to check the position of ")" and move the cursor more?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the `inputRef` prop direct in the `TextField` component.

Comment: @Tom A bit late, but that happens because the input component caret moves based on the input characters the user entered, but when you change its value programatically, the caret position doesn't change (after all, where should it be after the value is updated? so it stays where it was). This doesn't happen only with material-ui, but also with normal inputs. The logic to handle that can be complex if you don't know beforehand where the final position should be. If you know where it should be, then you can use the accepted answer code (which seems it was what you did).